# Почему круги другие классы не реагирует на ховер эффект?

Tags: html, css

Имеется такой код:

```css
.big-circle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 24.125rem;
  height: 24.125rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.normal-circle {
  width: 12.125rem;
  height: 12.125rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.play-video {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.play-video__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  top: 55%;
}
.play-video__button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.play-video__button:hover .normal-circle {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.play-video__button:hover .big-circle {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-circle">
  <div class="normal-circle">
    <div class="play-video">
      <i class="icon-play play-video__button"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Суть в том, что при наведении на красный квадратик по середине, линии вокруг должны менять цвет `border'a`, но этого не происходит.

Comment: Нельзя менять родителя при наведении на ребенка, но есть варианты, как это обойти https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) вот эти стили:

```
.play-video__button:hover .normal-circle {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.play-video__button:hover .big-circle {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

не сработают в принципе. В переводе на русский с css-ного они означают
`.normal-circle, вложенный в .play-video__button` и `.big-circle, вложенный в .play-video__button`. А у вас строго наоборот.

2) с помощью CSS НЕВОЗМОЖНО воздействовать на элемент, который является родительским или предшествующим. Только на потомков или ПОСЛЕДУЮЩИЕ элементы того же уровня (и их потомков).